# How to use the Observables from HttpClient and paramMap together for a dynamically loading component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient, rxjs5

I have an HTTPClient 'get' method that returns a JSON array of objects. In addition, I'm currently using a key from the route params to extract one object from that array.

The component is dynamic, meaning when the route param changes, the component won't get destroyed.

**The Problem**

When a new route param is switched, the component doesn't change the selectedUser objecct.

**Why?**

Because the httpClient completes the observable stream after one emitted item therefore the paramMap observable is also closed so it won't emit when a different value for the route param changes.

ex: '/user/:name'

1. '/user/bob' ---> component finds the selected user
2. from the component a new user is entered '/user/john'
3. '/user/john' ----> component doesn't detect the new param

Here is the code snippet below (users$ is the http.get() observable).

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.users$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.params$),
      map( ([users, params]) => {
        return users.find((user) => user.slug === params.landmark);
      })
    ).subscribe(user => this.selecteduser = user);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Switching to combineLatest does work, but I had to rearrange the observable as such:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.params$.pipe(
      combineLatest(this.users$, this.params$),
      map( ([params, users]) => {
        this.users = users;
        return users.find((user) => user.slug === params.landmark);
      })
    ).subscribe(user => this.selecteduser = user);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `combineLatest` instead of `withLatestFrom`. This will make the resulted stream active even after one stream completes.

```
ngOnInit() {
     combineLatest(this.users$, this.params$).pipe(
      map( ([users, params]) => {
        return users.find((user) => user.slug === params.landmark);
      })
    ).subscribe(user => this.selecteduser = user);
  }
```

Comment: When I try that syntax I get this error: "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<[{}, any, Params]>>'.

Comment: HOWEVER, your suggestion is correct. With the code I provided, after replacing 'withLatestFrom' with 'combineLatest'  I had to make the source observable the 'paramMap', and the second Observable is the HTTPClient, I wonder why that is

Comment: Do the correct import. Here combineLatest is a static method, not an operator. import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs';

Comment: So when using combineLatest, if an observable completes, it will just retain its last emitted item as its output, correct?

Comment: Exactly, as long as one of its parameter observables is emitting, combineLatest will be emitting and completes when all of its parameter observables complete.